# Android traceroute / nslookup with NDK

Tags: android, networking, android-ndk

I know that it is not possible to run `traceroute` or `nslookup` from an Android application. But is it possible using NDK without being root? Have anyone done this kind of work before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this source, hope help you:

https://code.google.com/p/yangapp/downloads/detail?name=busybox-1.20.2r2